# Importing old Disqus comments into WordPress

Tags: comments, disqus

Anyone got a working way to import old Disqus comments into WordPress?

Presumably by converting the [Disqus XML export format](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472149-comments-export) to the [WordPress XML import format](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content).

Note that [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comments-importer/) is for some ancient version of Disqus and doesn't work.

Comment: via http://www.jwz.org/blog/2012/11/disqus-wordpress/

Comment: Hi @JeffAtwood. As Plugin Recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations), are you searching for a code sample? If so, you could start with simply grabing the XML (SimpleXML for the rescue), loop through the result and use [`wp_insert_comment()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_insert_comment/). Shouldn't be that hard if you got a feed to retrieve your old ones from. [There're also some other questions around that topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=import+disqus).

Comment: @kaiser jwz is seeking a method of accomplishing the goal, the plugin was merely an example of one way you might achieve that goal. The title does not say "give me a plugin", the first line is "a working way to.."

Answer (score 1):

Without having a sample xml file, it's impossible to try to debug that plugin and see where it is failing. Tried to search if some innocent soul left a file hanging on the internets, but nope.

But one can see what others are saying: [The nightmare that is Disqus export, and import into WordPress](http://freethoughtblogs.com/lousycanuck/2011/09/20/the-nightmare-that-is-disqus-export-and-import-into-wordpress/).

<sup>*September 20, 2011*</sup>

> Disqus should have made this easy by using the generic WXR format, but
>   they haven’t, they went with their own schema. I’m out to prove this
>   kind of import can be done. It’s personal now. Share your Disqus
>   horror stories, or WordPress database-hacking stories here. Who knows?
>   Maybe you’ll have a solution I haven’t thought of.

---

And maybe, if it works as of now, adapt the following [Disqus Comments Importer Script in PHP](http://www.binarytides.com/disqus-comments-importer-script-in-php/) to route the output into a `wp_insert_comment` call.

<sup>*January 12, 2012*</sup>

> Recently I moved from Disqus to my own custom commenting system for
>   several reasons like more control over comment notifications to
>   authors, showing comments count anywhere easily, etc. So I had to
>   figure out a way to move about a hundred comments from Disqus's system
>   to my own Database. Googling did not help me find any good script for
>   such a requirement neither did Github Search yield anything. So, I
>   decided to give it a shot, took some time as I had to do it with
>   http://php.net/dom and had no previous experience but overall it
>   wasn't more than a day's task and most of it was a breeze. I would
>   like to share the code here just incase it helps others!